# Textview with rotate, zoom in,zoom out and move on touch in android?

Tags: android, textview

I want a text view with rotate, zoom in, zoom out and move functionalities,
basically i have a imageview on which I need to add a text view with these functionalities so the user can place its name as per requirement (edit of text is Just like WhatsApp and Instagram story)

Comment: please check https://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/ and https://github.com/ryanch741/android-view-rotate-zoom-single-finger

Answer (score 1):

show below library and check

https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView

https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView

https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView

https://github.com/shashi180493/StickerView